# Can't change account in Ubuntu One Control Center

Tags: accounts

My Ubuntu One Control Center on my computer uses one account. My Ubuntu One app on my android phone uses a different one. I want to change my account on my computer to the one that my phone uses but I can't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

Go to [your ubuntu  one account](https://one.ubuntu.com/account/machines/)

Remove your computer from the account you no longer wish to use.

Create new account, connect the account for your phone.

[image: existing account]

For more detailed instructions see : https://one.ubuntu.com/help/tutorial/install-and-setup-ubuntu-one/